# CGContextClip in drawRect is not working

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect, cgcontext

I've been trying to clip my view to make it pointed on the right, but for some reason, it's not working.

The following is my code in drawRect:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, width - 20.0, 0.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, width, height / 2.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, width - 20.0, height);

[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

CGContextClip(ctx);
```

I just put the stroke path to see if it's working.
Strokes are working fine, but CGContextClip() just won't work (without the stroke function) to save my life.

Please help me!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want something like traingle?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make a rectangle with a pointed right, like those things that allows you to navigate in a drill-down interface

Comment: So you can simply draw a rectangle using `CGContext`. Why are you clipping the path?

Comment: Oh....... I was just lazy and thought I'll just clip the existing rectangle. I'm new to programming, so I didn't realize. Do you mean, the drawRect is where the rect is getting drawn, so I should go ahead and draw the rectangle with my configuration? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a *triangle* using `CoreGraphics`

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect)/2, CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the hint from your comment so I got it sorted out :) Thanks a lot